# Constant timeouts in Cassandra after adding second node

Tags: java, cassandra, timeout

I'm trying to migrate a moderately large swath of data (~41 million rows) from an SQL database to Cassandra.  I've previously done a trial-run using half the dataset, and everything worked exactly as expected.

The problem is, now that I'm trying the complete migration Cassandra is throwing constant timeout errors.  For instance:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:10112 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out waiting for server response))
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.mycompany.tasks.CassandraMigrationTask.execute(CassandraMigrationTask.java:164)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:10112 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timed out waiting for server response))
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:108)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$1.run(RequestHandler.java:179)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've tried increasing the timeout values in `cassandra.yaml`, and that increased the amount of time that the migration was able to run before dying to a timeout (roughly in proportion to the increase in the timeout).

Prior to changing the timeout settings, my stack-trace looked more like:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:289)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.mycompany.tasks.CassandraMigrationTask.execute(CassandraMigrationTask.java:164)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:99)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:249)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:433)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:697)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.shaded.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.datastax.shaded.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70)
```

My timeout settings are currently:

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

...which gets me about 1.5m rows inserted before the timeout happens.  The original timeout settings were:

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
```

...which caused the timeouts to happen approximately every 300,000 rows.

The only significant change that's occurred between when I had my successful run and now is that I added a second node to the Cassandra deployment.  So intuitively I'd think the issue would have something to do with the propagation of data from the first node to the second (as in, there's `<some process>` that scales linearly with the amount of data inserted and which isn't used when there's only a single node).  But I'm not seeing any obvious options that might be useful for configuring/mitigating this.

If it's relevant, I'm using batch statements during the migration, typically with between 100 and 200 statements/rows per batch, at most.

My keyspace was originally set up `WITH REPLICATION =
  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2 }`, but I altered it to be `WITH REPLICATION =
  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }` to see if that would make any difference.  It didn't.

I also tried explicitly setting `ConsistencyLevel.ANY` on all my insert statements (and also the enclosing batch statements).  That also made no difference.

There doesn't seem to be anything interesting in Cassandra's log on either node, although the first node is certainly showing more 'ops' than the second:

**First node - 454317 ops**

```
INFO  [SlabPoolCleaner] 2016-01-25 19:46:08,806 ColumnFamilyStore.java:905 - Enqueuing flush of assetproperties_flat: 148265302 (14%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:15] 2016-01-25 19:46:08,807 Memtable.java:347 - Writing Memtable-assetproperties_flat@350387072(20.557MiB serialized bytes, 454317 ops, 14%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:15] 2016-01-25 19:46:09,393 Memtable.java:382 - Completed flushing /var/cassandra/data/itb/assetproperties_flat-e83359a0c34411e593abdda945619e28/itb-assetproperties_flat-tmp-ka-32-Data.db (5.249MiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1453767930194, position=15188257)
```

**Second node - 2020 ops**

```
INFO  [BatchlogTasks:1] 2016-01-25 19:46:33,961 ColumnFamilyStore.java:905 - Enqueuing flush of batchlog: 4923957 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:22] 2016-01-25 19:46:33,962 Memtable.java:347 - Writing Memtable-batchlog@796821497(4.453MiB serialized bytes, 2020 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:22] 2016-01-25 19:46:33,963 Memtable.java:393 - Completed flushing /var/cassandra/data/system/batchlog-0290003c977e397cac3efdfdc01d626b/system-batchlog-tmp-ka-11-Data.db; nothing needed to be retained.  Commitlog position was ReplayPosition(segmentId=1453767955411, position=18567563)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, what was the fix?

Would it be advisable to just take the second node offline, run the migration with just the first node, and then run `nodetool repair` afterwards to get the second node back in sync?

**Edit**

Answers to questions from comments:

1. I'm using the datastax Java driver, and have a server-side task ([Quartz job](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/)) that uses the ORM layer (hibernate) to lookup the next chunk of data to migrate, write it into Cassandra, and then purge it from the SQL database.  I'm getting a connection to Cassandra using the following code:

   ```
   public static Session getCassandraSession(String keyspace) {
       Session session = clusterSessions.get(keyspace);
       if (session != null && ! session.isClosed()) {
           //can use the cached session
           return session;
       }

       //create a new session for the specified keyspace
       Cluster cassandraCluster = getCluster();
       session = cassandraCluster.connect(keyspace);

       //cache and return the session
       clusterSessions.put(keyspace, session);
       return session;
   }

   private static Cluster getCluster() {
       if (cluster != null && ! cluster.isClosed()) {
           //can use the cached cluster
           return cluster;
       }

       //configure socket options
       SocketOptions options = new SocketOptions();
       options.setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000);
       options.setReadTimeoutMillis(300000);
       options.setTcpNoDelay(true);

       //spin up a fresh connection
       cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(Configuration.getCassandraHost()).withPort(Configuration.getCassandraPort())
                   .withCredentials(Configuration.getCassandraUser(), Configuration.getCassandraPass()).withSocketOptions(options).build();

       //log the cluster details for confirmation
       Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
       LOG.debug("Connected to Cassandra cluster: " + metadata.getClusterName());
       for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
           LOG.debug("Datacenter:  " + host.getDatacenter() + "; Host:  " + host.getAddress() + "; Rack: " + host.getRack());
       }

       return cluster;
   }
   ```

   The part with the `SocketOptions` is a recent addition, as the latest timeout error sounded like it was coming from the Java/client side rather than from within Cassandra itself.
2. Each batch inserts no more than 200 records.  Typical values are closer to 100.
3. Both nodes have the same specs:

   - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz
   - 32GB RAM
   - 256GB SSD (primary), 2TB HDD (backups), both in RAID-1 configurations
4. **First node:**

   ```
   Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
   CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
   ReadStage                         0         0          58155         0                 0
   RequestResponseStage              0         0         655104         0                 0
   MutationStage                     0         0         259151         0                 0
   ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
   GossipStage                       0         0          58041         0                 0
   CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
   AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
   MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
   Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
   ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
   CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
   MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
   MemtableFlushWriter               0         0             80         0                 0
   MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0             80         0                 0
   PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              3         0                 0
   MemtablePostFlush                 0         0            418         0                 0
   CompactionExecutor                0         0           8979         0                 0
   InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
   HintedHandoff                     0         0              2         0                 0
   Native-Transport-Requests         1         0        1175338         0                 0

   Message type           Dropped
   RANGE_SLICE                  0
   READ_REPAIR                  0
   PAGED_RANGE                  0
   BINARY                       0
   READ                         0
   MUTATION                     0
   _TRACE                       0
   REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
   COUNTER_MUTATION             0
   ```

   **Second node:**

   ```
   Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
   CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
   ReadStage                         0         0          55803         0                 0
   RequestResponseStage              0         0              1         0                 0
   MutationStage                     0         0         733828         0                 0
   ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
   GossipStage                       0         0          56623         0                 0
   CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
   AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
   MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
   Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
   ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
   CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
   MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
   MemtableFlushWriter               0         0            394         0                 0
   MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0            394         0                 0
   PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              2         0                 0
   MemtablePostFlush                 0         0            428         0                 0
   CompactionExecutor                0         0           8883         0                 0
   InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
   HintedHandoff                     0         0              1         0                 0
   Native-Transport-Requests         0         0             70         0                 0

   Message type           Dropped
   RANGE_SLICE                  0
   READ_REPAIR                  0
   PAGED_RANGE                  0
   BINARY                       0
   READ                         0
   MUTATION                     0
   _TRACE                       0
   REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
   COUNTER_MUTATION             0
   ```
5. The output of `nodetool ring` was very long.  Here's a `nodetool status` instead:

   ```
   Datacenter: DC1
   ===============
   Status=Up/Down
   |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
   --  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
   UN  204.11.xxx.1  754.66 MB  1024    ?       8cf373d8-0b3e-4fd3-9e63-fdcdd8ce8cd4  RAC1
   UN  208.66.xxx.2  767.78 MB  1024    ?       42e1f336-84cb-4260-84df-92566961a220  RAC2
   ```
6. I increased all of Cassandra's timeout values by a factor of 10, and also set the Java driver's read timeout settings to match, and now I'm up to <s>8m</s> 29.4m inserts with no issues.  In theory if the issue scales linearly with the timeout values I should be good up until around 15m inserts (which is at least good enough that I don't need to constantly babysit the migration process waiting for each new error).

Comment: A few questions to help us get in the right direction - 1. How are you migrating your data? Are you using a JDBC connection? Loading a file? 2. You mentioned "(and also the enclosing batch statements)" - how large are each batch insert (how many records)? 3. What type of hardware are you running this on? What type of hard drives are you using? 4. Lastly, an output of nodetool tpstats will also help.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing that'll help is nodetool ring to get an idea of token distribution since your first node did so many ops. Either node 1 owns most of the token range or you have a few very large partitions on that node which would make this a data model issue.

Comment: @MarcintheCloud - Okay, updated with the requested info.

Comment: Can you show us the source code from your client inserting data ? Are you using prepared statement ? Are you using synchronous or async calls ? etc ...

Comment: Yes, using `PreparedStatement`.  And running them using [Session.execute()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#execute-com.datastax.driver.core.Statement-), so synchronous execution.

Comment: Hi Aroth, thanks for answering all the questions. The tough thing is that it seems like you've done everything right except I did notice something that could be causing the issue. I noticed that it says you're using 1024 tokens. In the cassandra.yaml did you set num_tokens: 1024? That's extremely high. The most you'd ever want is 256 and even then, it's considered a little high. Increasing timeouts is usually not the answer and hides the problem, usually temporarily.

Comment: @MarcintheCloud - Yes, I did increase `num_tokens` to 1024.  Not for any specific reason, but more because the comments for that setting in the default `cassandra.yaml` file made it sound like the only thing that mattered was relative magnitude as compared to other nodes.  If 1024 is too high, can I just reduce it to 256 on both nodes and restart, or is it too late for that?

Comment: There's no easy way to go back to 256. You'll have to blast the data directories and start from scratch essentially. If you're not planning on having 100's of nodes, I suggest maybe sticking to 64 for num_tokens. I think that might take care of your problem though, seeing that everything else you're doing looks normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to get the timeout errors to stop by doing two things.  First, I increased Cassandra's timeout values on both hosts, as follows:

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 30000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

I suspect those values are unnecessarily large, but those are what I had in place when everything started working.

The second part of the solution was to adjust the client timeout in my Java code, as follows:

```
//configure socket options
SocketOptions options = new SocketOptions();
options.setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000);
options.setReadTimeoutMillis(300000);
options.setTcpNoDelay(true);

//spin up a fresh connection (using the SocketOptions set up above)
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(Configuration.getCassandraHost()).withPort(Configuration.getCassandraPort())
            .withCredentials(Configuration.getCassandraUser(), Configuration.getCassandraPass()).withSocketOptions(options).build();
```

With those two changes, the timeout errors stopped and the data migration completed without issue.

As @MarcintheCloud rightly points out in the comments above, increasing the timeout values may only have the effect of masking the underlying problem.  But that's good enough in my case since 1) the underlying problem only surfaces under very high load, 2) I only need to run the migration process once, and 3) once the data has been migrated, the actual load levels are orders of magnitude lower than what's experienced during the migration.

However, understanding the underlying cause still seems worthwhile.  So what was it?  Well I've got two theories:

1. As @MarcintheCloud posits, perhaps 1024 is too many tokens to reasonably use with Cassandra.  And perhaps as a consequence of that the deployment gets a bit flaky under heavy load.
2. My alternative theory has to do with network chatter between the two nodes.  In my deployment, the first node runs the app-server instance, the first Cassandra instance, and the primary SQL database.  The second node runs the second Cassandra instance and also a replica SQL database that is kept in sync with the primary database in near-real-time.

   Now, the migration process essentially does two things concurrently; it writes data into Cassandra, and it deletes data from the SQL database.  Both of those actions generate changesets that need to propagate over the network to the second node.

   So my theory is that if changes are happening quickly enough on the first node (since the SSD *does* allow very high IO throughput), the network transfers of the SQL and Cassandra changelogs (and/or the subsequent IO ops on the second node) may occasionally contend with each other, introducing additional latency into the replication process(es) and potentially leading to timeouts.  It seems plausible that with enough contention, one process or the other might get blocked for several seconds at a time, which is enough to trigger timeout errors at Cassandra's default settings.

Those are the plausible theories I can think of.  Though no real way of testing to confirm which (if any) is correct.

Comment: I had a similar problem, it turned out to be long GC pauses on the CLIENT side.  The driver will report it as a timeout waiting for the server, even if the server responds during the GC.

Answer (score 4):

1) CL.ANY is almost always a bad idea - you're writing faster than the server can even acknowledge the writes.

2) 1024 tokens is silly, but not the cause of the problems. You also can't change it once the node is live in the cluster.

3) You're masking your problems by increasing the timeouts - cassandra on that hardware can run easily 100k writes/second.

4) Batches are meant for atomicity, you're probably misusing them, which is adding headache.

5) You've tuned all sorts of knobs without understanding them. Cassandra is different than a relational DB.

6) The right way to do data loads of this nature is with CQLSSTableWriter and the bulk load interface. Details at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

7) When the client starts throwing errors, what's in the server logs? What's the JVM doing? Are you seeing GC pauses? Is the server idle? CPU maxed? Disks maxed?

8) There exist some very good tuning guides - consider reading and understanding https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html

Comment: 1) Based on the error logs, Cassandra ignored the CL.ANY anyways and used CL.ONE instead, 3) I openly acknowledge as much, however a successful migration is a successful migration, 4) atomicity is _exactly_ why I'm using the batches, 6) using an external tool is _definitely_ not the "right" approach here, I need to maintain a consistent state between Cassandra and the RDB during the process; at no point do I want two live copies of the data, or zero, 7) I included the relevant portion of the logs; "no" and "mostly idle" are the answers to the other things.